# How to save a newly cut dracaena without leaves

Tags: dracaena

I tried to get a cut from my dracaena and propagate it before travelling. Unfortunately when we arrived the cut was damaged - the leaves were cut off.

Now I'm afraid that it doesn't have any roots yet, neither leaves, so it may not survive.

Is it better to keep it in a pot, or should I instead put it in a glass of water until roots start to appear?

You can find below pictures of the new cut without leaves and the mother plant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there, can you add a picture so we can see what type of dracaena?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion - I've added a picture of the cut, and a picture of the mother plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These plants are fairly resilient and can be propagated by putting a cutting in the soil like you have done or putting them in water. If you put in water it's easier to see the progress of the cutting. Don't let it sit too long in water once the roots are an inch long it can be re potted.

New shoots will start from around the top of the stem when it's ready

I see this plant is now known as [Dracaena reflexa var. angustifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_marginata) but the care conditions remain the same:

- in countries well north of the equator (USA, Canada, Europe) full sun, easy on the water, watch for spider mites
- in countries near the equator where there is a lot more light place in some shade